# Error in compiling a simple assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm learning asm and now saw a script, but I can't compile it:

```
section .text
    global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:                     ;tell linker entry point
    mov     edx, [ebp+input_file]
    mov     eax, [edx+8]
    movsx   ecx, word ptr [eax]
    push    ecx
    mov     edx, [ebp+input_file]
    mov     eax, [edx+8]
    push    eax
    mov     ecx, [ebp+var_8]
    mov     edx, [ecx+2748h]
    push    edx
    call    memcpy
    int     0x80        ;call kernel
    mov     eax, 1      ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int     0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
```

When I compile this code using:

```
nasm -f elf *.asm; ld -m elf_i386 -s -o demo *.o
```

I get this result:

> Error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand                                                                         >
>   ld: cannot find *.o: No such file or directory

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure there was no line number with that error message? It would help in case of longer source to mark line, which is causing problems.

Comment: exactly it was a cut of code that I tried to put that in a simple hello world script. and now I'm seeing that input_file,var_8 are undefined @Ped7g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ptr` is an not a defined key word in NASM. Just remove it (in line 6) and your code will compile:

```
movsx   ecx, word [eax]
```